# How to use LINQ in Mono?

Tags: linq, mono, monodevelop

I can't make System.Linq (aka LINQ to Objects) work. I am running MonoDevelop 2.2.1 in Ubuntu 10 Lucid Lynx with Mono 2.4.4.

They advertise in their site that they implemented LINQ, but I can't even find `Enumerable.Range` or `ToArray()`. What's wrong?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I guess what you would need to do is:

1. In your project options set "Runtime version" to "Mono/.Net 3.5"
2. Add reference to System.Core package (right click references in solution explorer)
3. Add "using System.Linq" to your module

after that your code should compile and execute

hope this helps, regards

Comment: All I needed was to add a reference to System.Core

Comment: where do you set the runtime version? I don't see such option in project settings

Comment: Oddly enough, it would compile and run for me without the reference to System.Core, but I had no intellisense, and the using statement had "Linq" highlighted in red.  Adding System.Core fixed this niggle.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using the `gmcs` compiler?  `mcs` does not seem to compile code containing Linq.

```
$ cat a.cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        foreach (var i in new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.Where(n => n % 2 == 0))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
$ gmcs a.cs
$ ./a.exe
2
4
```

To compile with `gmcs`, perform the following instructions as described by [the MonoDevelop FAQ](http://monodevelop.com/FAQ):

> #### Can I compile my project with gmcs?
>
> Yes. Right click on your project, select 'Options'->'Runtime' and select '2.0' from the drop-down list.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean when you say "can't find"?  Intellisense?  Many of the linq methods are extension methods, and monodevelop may not support those in intellisense. In which case you can still use them and your code should compile, it just isn't in the drop-downs.

[About extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)